# Rails and Devise - Namespace is Uninitialised Constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, routes, namespaces

I am trying to use namespaces to declare an api.

My *routes.rb* contains:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    namespace :api do
      namespace :v1 do
        match 'log_in', :to => 'token_authentications#log_in', :via => "post"
      end
    end
  end
```

And my *token_authentications_controller.rb* looks like this:

```
class Api::V1::TokenAuthenticationsController < ApplicationController

...

  def log_in

  ...

  end

...

end
```

When I hit: api/v1/log_in I get:

> Routing Error 
>   uninitialized constant Api

So do I need to declare the namespace somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rails expects namespaces to follow directory structure, unless I'm mistaken.

Given your class name for your controller, `Api::V1::TokenAuthenticationsController`, rails expects it to live in `app/controllers/api/v1/token_authentications_controller.rb`.

If you just move your controller to the correct folder, I think you should be fine.

You might also want to make sure to actually declare the namespace modules somewhere, like for instance refactoring your controller as such:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class TokenAuthenticationsController

...

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It was the folder structure. No need for declaring the modules. It must be implicit. Thanks.

Comment: @Frost What if I just want to add a namespace to the url and not change the directory structure or preffix the module name to the controller name?

Comment: Okay I got it. I should just use `scope` instead of `namespace`.